# vlookup for different columns simultaneously filling the whole sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Below is a code that I found here : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/123670/is-there-a-way-to-emulate-vlookup-in-google-script
I tried to optimize it to my use case in which
to vlookup from source sheet 'data', and fill in values in destination sheet 's'. The problem is that this code does this only for one row. Is there a way to loop over all rows and vlookup and fill in efficiently?

```
/* recall that we want the follwoing columns  => E, F, G, H, M
/*/
 function khalookup(){
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();     

 var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mysheetid");

 var searchValue = s.getRange("B2:B").getValues();

 var dataValues = data.getRange("A3:A").getValues();

 var dataList = dataValues.join("ღ").split("ღ");

 var index = dataList.indexOf([searchValue]);
  

  var newRange = []
  var row = index + 3;

  var foundValue = data.getRange("E"+row).getValue();
  var foundValue1 = data.getRange("F"+row).getValue();
  var foundValue2 = data.getRange("G"+row).getValue();
  var foundValue3 = data.getRange("H"+row).getValue();
  var foundValue4 = data.getRange("M"+row).getValue();
  s.getRange("K2").setValue(foundValue);
  
  s.getRange("L2").setValue(foundValue1);
  s.getRange("M2").setValue(foundValue2);
  s.getRange("N2").setValue(foundValue3);
  s.getRange("O2").setValue(foundValue4);


 }
```

here is the source sheet where the vlookup shall happen based on the ID "Column A"

[image: source sheet]

And here is how the destination sheet shall look like after the vlookup based on ID "Column B" have been made.

[image: Destination Sheet]

Comment: refer to here for compact and easy solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/72575380/19240194

Answer (score 2):

### You can do iterate with a loop, e.g. a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Assuming you would like to loop through all rows from `index + 3` to the [last row](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow), you can modify your code as following:

```js
...
var row = index + 3;
var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
for (var i = row; i <= lastRow; i++){
  var foundValue = data.getRange("E"+i).getValue();
  var foundValue1 = data.getRange("F"+i).getValue();
  var foundValue2 = data.getRange("G"+i).getValue();
  var foundValue3 = data.getRange("H"+i).getValue();
  var foundValue4 = data.getRange("M"+i).getValue();

  s.getRange("K" + (2+i-row)).setValue(foundValue);  
  s.getRange("L" + (2+i-row)).setValue(foundValue1);
  s.getRange("M" + (2+i-row)).setValue(foundValue2);
  s.getRange("N" + (2+i-row)).setValue(foundValue3);
  s.getRange("O" + (2+i-row)).setValue(foundValue4);
}
```

Note that later on you might want to progress from using `getValue()` and `setValue()` to [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) - that will make your code execution faster.

Comment: it still kinda populates wrong values, is there any way to debug it!! like change the indexing logic?

Comment: Sure, you can change the indexing as desired. Which values would you like to populate?

Comment: `var dataList = dataValues.join("ღ").split("ღ");

 var index = dataList.indexOf([searchValue]);
  
  var row = index + 3;`                                                                                                         I Think this part is causing erroneous indexing, I want to get values in cols [E,F,G,H,M] from source sheet and copy to destination sheet in these cols [K, L, M, N, O] respectively. is there a better way to do it.

Comment: If you want to copy the values from E,F,G,H,M into the same row of K, L, M, N, O - you simply need to index the destination range in the same way like the origin range - in this case: `s.getRange("K" + i).setValue(foundValue); ` etc. instead of `s.getRange("K" + (2+i-row)).setValue(foundValue); `.

Comment: I have tried it but still getting erroneous values, is there a better way to loop over the spreadsheet, and another way to index it than above?

Comment: What do you mean by erroneous values? Are the values themselves erroneous or their location in the destinaiton range.To udnerstand what the correct / best way of looping and copying the values is, it would be helpful to see your spreadsheet and screenshots showing which values you would like to copy to where.

Comment: the location of the values in the destination range is incorrect, is it because the ID column in source sheet is sorted but in destination sheet is not sorted? Furthermore, I have added more description and screenshots above for how the source and destination sheets shall look like.

Comment: Oh, I see - your data is sorted! I think this is the problem, you should copy your unsorted dat and sort it later. Also, the vlookup formula for the destination range should be adapted to the respective range notation.

Comment: do you have any idea, how I can do that ? I am litrally debugging since days and reaching no solution. I wonder why when I compare two identical columns from different sheets, I still get wrong value at destination sheet? Furthermore, I cannot unsort the source sheet ...